# How to check if there are doubles in the same line?

Tags: regex, date, vim

I have a text file with many lines like this:

```
IMG_0106.JPG    y:\2004_05_23_bern basel\       2004_05_23
IMG_0107.JPG    y:\2004_05_23_dortmund\         2004_05_23
IMG_0108.JPG    y:\2004_05_25_paris\            2004_05_24
IMG_0110.JPG    y:\2004_05_25_paris\            2004_05_25
```

I want to check if there are double dates in the same line
and where not.

Line 1,2,4 have a date match.
Line 3 doesn't have a date match (2004_05_25 != 2004_05_24)

I know how to find double lines but I don't know how to find doubles in the same line in this case.
Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this `:g` command with regex would give you those lines with duplicated dates, you can do your operations on those lines:

```
:g/\v(\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}).*\1
```

if you just want to find them, (or highlight them with hlsearch), just do `/sameRegex`

Comment: Thank you kent:) what does `\1`? Btw do you know the negative way (how to highlight only the non matching items)?

Comment: @Remonn `\1` reference group1, `\2` references group 2, and so on. here the `\1` is the previously matched date ( in `(..)`).  if you want to select those unmatches, use `v:/...` instead of `:g/...`

Comment: thank you, I thought that your regex would match also line 3 in my question but it works fine (still don't know why it doesn't match line 3). and.. I Want to highlight only the dates but I'll find it out. :) Thank you very much!

Comment: ,Still haven't found how to highlight only the dates and not the text in between. Do you know this?

Comment: that :g or :v finds out lines with dup/un-dup dates. matched part is highlighted. If you want to do further highlighting. it is another topic.  For hi one date in matched lines, you could : `v/\v\zs(\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2})\ze.*\1/`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
grep '\([0-9]\{4\}_[0-9]\{2\}_[0-9]\{2\}\).*\1'
```